# Difference between ngSrc and ngSrcset

Tags: angularjs

I didn't get clarity on 'ngSrcset', when i have gone through the Angular API reference docs. Can someone clarify with an example.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrcset

Answer (score 7):

Probably the easiest way to understand it is to analyze what happens when the page loads in each case.

### Let's take a look at the "standard/buggy" example:

```
<img srcset="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}} 2x"/>`
```

Here is what happens:

- DOM loads
- attribute `srcset` found and recognized
- a request is made to `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}`, which doesn't exist, of course, so we get a 404
- Angular fires up
- Angular interpolates template strings in DOM elements
- now we finally get something like `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/realHash`, which is what we needed

---

### Now let's take a look at the correct example:

```
<img ng-srcset="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}} 2x"/>`
```

Here is what happens:

- DOM loads
- `ng-srcset` attribute is found, but not recognized, so no server calls are made
- Angular fires up
- Angular interpolates template strings in DOM elements taking into account all the ng-* attributes
- `srcset` attribute is created from the interpolated value of `ng-srcset` so we instantly get something like: `<img ng-srcset="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}} 2x" srcset= "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/realHash 2x" />`, which is exactly what we want.
- newly added `srcset` attribute is found and recognized, so the server make a call to `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/realHash`, and all is good

The same principle works for `ng-src`, `ng-href`, etc.

---

Here's an interesting article about the scrset itself: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/21/webkit-implements-srcset-and-why-its-a-good-thing/

Comment: What does this `2px` mean inside ng-srcset?

Comment: @AnakiiEugene it's the pixel density. Other values are supported as well, so you can serve different images to devices with different pixel density screens.

Answer (score 1):

What it's saying is that bindings might not work inside srcset.

For example you might have something like $scope.test = "destination/picture.jpg"

if you use `<img ng-srcset="{{test}}"/>`

It will find the image in the location destination/picture.jpg

Where as if you use `<img srcset="{{test}}"/>`

Sometimes it might search the image in the location "{{test}}" instead of "destination/picture.jpg".  This is not always the case hence "buggy way of doing it", in some cases it might work and in others it might not.

Answer (score 1):

**Srcset:** Srcset is a new attribute added in html5. We can use srcset for defining multiple source URL for a single image so that different resolution images can be rendered based the current screen size. Lets see an example,

```
<img src="low-res.jpg" srcset="high-res.jpg 2x">
```

html5 compatible browser will render low-res.jpg for smaller screen size and  will render high-res.jpg for larger screen(2x). In the above example, using src attribute will make sure that by default low-res.jpg could be rendered if the browser doesn't support html5.

For having a better idea about srcset attribute you should try to read the following nice article:
[srcset explained](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/21/webkit-implements-srcset-and-why-its-a-good-thing/)

**ngSrcset:** Using ngSrcset attribute make sure if any expression used in ng-srcset attribute could be parsed by angular app.

So following will **not work** ,

```
<img src="low-res.jpg" srcset="{{src}} 2x"> <!-- {{src}} is not expanded by angularjs -->
```

Whereas following **works fine**:

```
<img src="low-res.jpg" ng-srcset="{{src}} 2x"> <!--works fine -->
```

**ngSrc:** Similar reasoning applies for ng-src attribute. ngSrc attributes can parse the angular expression written in ng-src attribute whereas expression used in src attribute would not be parsed by angularjs.

```
<img src="{{src}}"> <!--will not work,"{{src}}" will not be parsed by angularjs -->
<img ng-src="{{src}}"> <!--works fine, "{{src}}" will be evaluated by angularjs -->
```